# F# laziness in quoted computation expressions

Tags: f#, f#-3.0, computation-expression

Using the Quote member on a computation expression to convert the workflow into an AST, but would like it be such that the `GetEnumerator()` is not actually called on the sequence as the quotation is constructed (i.e., have some form of laziness). In my use case, the sequence represents a remote data-source, and invoking the `GetEnumerator()` member on it will actually go out and query against it.

1. Is there some way to implicitly use the Lazy type (and still use the Quote member) on
    the Source member so that it does not eagerly call `GetEnumerator()` and instead has
    simply not loaded the value yet?
2. Why is a let binding defined as a property of a module and a variable within another
    function treated as different entities in the quotation, i.e. `PropertyGet` vs
    `Value`.

Some test code...

```
module Example

    open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

    [<Interface>]
    type I<'Type> =
        inherit seq<'Type>

    type FooBuilder() =

        member __.Source (x : #seq<'Type>) : I<'Type> = invalidOp "not implemented"

        member __.For (source : I<'Type>, f : 'Type -> I<'Type>) : I<'Type> = invalidOp "not implemented"

        member __.Zero () : I<'Type> = invalidOp "not implemented"

        member __.Quote (expr : Expr<#seq<'Type>>) = expr

        member __.Run (expr : Expr<#seq<'Type>>) =
            System.Console.WriteLine(expr)

    let foo = FooBuilder()

    let bar = [1; 2; 3]
    foo {
        for x in bar do ()
    }

    let insideLet() =
        let bar = [1; 2; 3]
        foo {
            for x in bar do ()
        }

    insideLet()
```

which results in the following two quotations

```
Call (Some (Value (FSI_0009+FooBuilder)), For,
      [Call (Some (Value (FSI_0009+FooBuilder)), Source,
             [PropertyGet (None, bar, [])]),
       Lambda (_arg1,
               Let (x, _arg1,
                    Sequential (Value (<null>),
                                Call (Some (Value (FSI_0009+FooBuilder)), Zero,
                                      []))))])

Call (Some (Value (FSI_0009+FooBuilder)), For,
      [Call (Some (Value (FSI_0009+FooBuilder)), Source, [Value ([1; 2; 3])]),
       Lambda (_arg1,
               Let (x, _arg1,
                    Sequential (Value (<null>),
                                Call (Some (Value (FSI_0009+FooBuilder)), Zero,
                                      []))))])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some way to implicitly use the Lazy type (and still use the Quote member) on the Source member so that it does not eagerly call GetEnumerator() and instead has simply not loaded the value yet?

I don't think there is a way to implicitly use the Lazy type. However, I do not quite understand the question - when you use the `Quote` method, you can perform any transformation on the quotation that you get, so you can transform the quotation so that it does not actually call the `GetEnumerator` member (of course, you'll have to replace it wiht something else that returns the data...)

The key thing is that building the query does not call the `GetEnumerator` method. So you should be able to get the quotation & transform it & evaluate it without calling `GetEnumerator`.

> Why is a let binding defined as a property of a module and a variable within another function treated as different entities in the quotation, i.e. `PropertyGet` vs `Value`.

A let binding in a module is compiled into a static member and so the quotation captures a reference to this static member. For local variables, capturing references is not possible, so the `Value` node embeds the data directly into the quotation. (You could write a transformation that turns `PropertyGet` into `Value` by actually getting the current value from the property)

**EDIT**: When I create an `IEnumerable` that throws when `GetEnumerator` is called, then the printed quotation in F# interactive shows the error (because F# interactive tries to evaluate the sequence to output first few members), but the quotation just contains the source as `Value`.

If you remove the `Run` method from your builder (so that it just returns the quotation), then this should work (and return the "fancy source" string):

```
type FancySource() = 
  member x.Source = "fancy source"
  interface seq<int> with
    member x.GetEnumerator() = failwith "!" 
  interface System.Collections.IEnumerable with
    member x.GetEnumerator() = failwith "!" 

let insideLet() =
  let bar = new FancySource()
  foo { for x in bar do () }

match insideLet() with
| Patterns.Call(_, _, Patterns.Call(_, _, [Patterns.Value(:? FancySource as v, _)])::_) -> 
    v.Source
```

Comment: In the call to Source, the arguments are a singleton list containing a Value. With my example, it is the list [1; 2; 3], but with my remote data-source, it is a sequence over the results. So `GetEnumerator()` is somehow called internally in order to generate that.

Comment: @user2712561 I think it does not actually call `GetEnumerator`.. See the edit.